# What sort of interfaces would be represented by an IANA ifType of l3ipvlan(136)?

Tags: networking, snmp, mib

On a router, switch, or similar network device with interfaces implementing the [ifType mib](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ianaiftype-mib), what exactly is meant by an ifType of l3ipvlan? I can see the phrase "Layer 3 Virtual LAN using IP" readily enough, but I'm not sure what the implications of that are, as it's not a networking object I'm familiar with. (I mean, I know what a 802.1Q VLAN is, but not layer 3.)

```
...
 atmSubInterface (134),  -- ATM Sub Interface
 l2vlan (135),           -- Layer 2 Virtual LAN using 802.1Q
 l3ipvlan (136),         -- Layer 3 Virtual LAN using IP
 l3ipxvlan (137),        -- Layer 3 Virtual LAN using IPX
 digitalPowerline (138), -- IP over Power Lines 
 mediaMailOverIp (139),  -- Multimedia Mail over IP
...
```

I [found a document](http://www.iana.org/assignments/smi-numbers) with certain technical references, but it didn't have anything I could comprehend:

```
 Registry:
 Decimal   Name          Description                      Reference
 -------   ------------  -------------------------------  ---------
       1   other         none of the following            [RFC1213]
       2   regular1822   BBN Report 1822                  [RFC1213]
       3   hdh1822       BBN Report 1822                  [RFC1213]
 ...
     135   l2vlan      Layer 2 Virtual LAN using 802.1Q             [MacFaden]          
     136   l3ipvlan    Layer 3 Virtual LAN - IP Protocol            [MacFaden]          
     137   l3ipxvlan   Layer 3 Virtual LAN - IPX Prot.              [MacFaden]
```

Answer (score 0):

IPVLAN is similar to MACVLAN with the difference being that the endpoints have the same MAC address.

See https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#ipvlan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as an l3ipvlan being an interface on the network device which is not configured as an access or trunk interface, but a virtual or sub interface associated with a vlan that has an ip address configured on it. These interfaces are typically used as gateways.

Answer (score -2):

All interfaces are of a specific type. This is just a description of available types. In your example, you give a IANA Interface Type of **l3ipvlan**, which means that if you were to SNMP Get from an SNMP Agent with such a device, you would get a value of **136**, which you should interpret as **l3ipvlan**.

Comment: Hey dude. You seem to have missed the point: what the heck **is** an l3ipvlan?

Comment: Then you should be state your question to something like: What is an IP VLAN? Your header question and the question in the body are a bit ambiguous. It sounds like you're asking about OID resolution.

Comment: @  *what is* he[sic] diff between "what exactly is meant by *an* ifType of *l3ipvlan*?"  and "What is an IP VLAN?"